# JQuery window.scroll() not working for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll, onscroll

I am working on a Infinite scroll (on a div which have large number of subdiv) 
infinite scroll is working for Desktop device but not for mobile devices
i checked that window.scroll function not getting fired for mobile device
i checked for some other events like OnTouchStart etc .. but none is working

Here is infinite scroll fiddle [Infinite Scroll Fiddle](https://codepen.io/vicmathur/pen/XgPeNa)

Here is infinite scroll project code example

```
infinitescroll: function() {

    var $doc=$(document);
    var $win=$(window);
    var itemsPerScroll=5;

    // hide everything that is out of bound
    $('.scroll').filter(function(index){
        return (($(this).offset().top) > $win.height());
    }).hide();

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        #event.preventDefault();
        alert("here");

        if ($doc.height()-$win.height()-$(this).scrollTop() == 0) {      
            $('.scroll:hidden:lt('+itemsPerScroll+')').show();
        }

    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter the code to this and it should fix it -

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows 
Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) == false) {
$(document).height() - window.visualViewport.height;
$('.article').filter(function(index){
return (($(this).offset().top) > $win.height());
}).hide();

$(window).scroll(function(){ 
if ($doc.height()-$win.height()-$(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
$('.article:hidden:lt('+itemstoshow+')').show();
        }
})};
```